# How to change GCC preprocessor output format?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

How can I change the gcc preprocessor (cc1.exe) output to this format:

```
 #line 1 "path/to/file.c"
```

Currently, I am getting this format:

```
 # 1 "path/to/file.c"
```

It also states [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html#Line-Control) that the output is a `#line` directive, but I am getting a different output format. Is there a parameter option that I need to use?

Comment: `cc1` is the C front end, not just the preprocessor (I think processing is integrated into the front end). Normally preprocessor output is just fed directly to the rest of the compiler. Why do you need to change it?

Comment: Speaking for myself, I want to do this because I want to preprocess the input to `yacc`; but `yacc` only understands `#line` directives, not `# <n>` directives.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer, just write a script to process the file generated by gcc preprocessor to stasfy your requirement.

1. Write a script by yourself, which take the output of the GCC preprocessor as the input, and replace the `# 1` with `#line 1`, named as `myscript`.
2. Write a script  to automatically call GCC preprocesss first  ,and then call your script `myscript`.
3. Name the above script in Step 2--`gcc`, put it in your local PATH.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for something simpler, like adding a parameter option.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html),

> Source file name and line number information is conveyed by lines of the form
>
> ```
> # linenum filename flags
> ```
>
> These are called linemarkers. They are inserted as needed into the output (but never within a string or character constant). They mean that the following line originated in file *filename* at line *linenum*.

The source you referenced is talking about preprocessor *input*, not output. (GCC also accepts the above format as input, too, but it's not interoperable.)